# I am getting ValueError at /car/offer/4/ Cannot assign "4": "CarRent.car" must be a "Car" instance. when trying to save Car instance to form

Tags: python, django

I am working on a car rental website for uber drivers in django, from the detailView I need drivers to be able to choose the duration of their rental, and other information will be auto filled to the form from my views.py, i was able to get the driver through request.user, i also need the PK of the car to be rented. searching through here i’ve tried various suggestions by people here, but i keep getting one error after another…

using
`self.kwargs['pk']` results in `ValueError at /car/offer/4/ Cannot assign "4": "CarRent.car" must be a "Car" instance.`

then i tried using
`form.car = Car.objects.get(pk= self.kwargs.get('pk'))` which results in a `AttributeError at /car/offer/4/ 'CarRent' object has no attribute 'is_valid'`

can someone please tell me how to get the car instance saved in the CarRent model? any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

below is my code (reduced to the relevant bit)

models.py

```
class Car(models.Model):
    car_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='car_owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class CarRent(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='rented_car', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='driver_renting', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rented_weeks = models.BigIntegerField(default=1, choices=WEEK_CHOICES)
```

forms.py

```
class RentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CarRent
        fields = ['rented_weeks']
```

i’m only displaying the rented weeks as that’s the only information i need from the user.

views.py

```
class CarView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Car
    form_class = RentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('car-details', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()

        form = form.save(commit=False)
      

        form.car = self.kwargs['pk']

        form.driver = request.user

        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form.car` expects a `Car` object, not a string with the primary key, but you can simply use:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class CarView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    # …

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form = self.get_form()
            self.object = self.get_object()
            if form.is_valid():
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(form)
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.car_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.driver = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: @Williem Thanks for the solution, however using the method you provided above raises a ` NameError, name 'request' is not defined ` any idea why i'm getting that?

Comment: @AbdulGiwa: it is `self.request.user`, not `request.user`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, Thanks. On using settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL as advised, will there be a side effect if i don't add it to my post_save signal?

Comment: @AbdulGiwa: no, normally not. But signals itself are often an antipattern: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/ a lot of ORM calls can also circument signals.